# Error messages not showing up on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making validations for my rails app, and the validation is working. However, it still displays the success message and it does not display the error message. I'm sure I am missing something simple! Here is my code.

```
def create
  @message = Message.create(message_params)
  if @message.send_at.blank?
    Person.in_groups(message_params[:group_ids]).each do |person|
      person.delay.send_message(@message.body)
      flash[:success] = "Messages on their way!"
    end
  else
    Person.in_groups(message_params[:group_ids]).each do |person|
      person.delay(run_at: @message.send_at).send_message(@message.body)
      flash[:success] = "Messages on their way!"
    end
  end
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

hers is my view

```
<% if @message.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% @message.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: ... what error message? There aren't any in the code you posted. Post your view, if you are only after validation errors that might be the place to look.

Comment: Your create method redirects whether the creation is successful or not. When you redirect, you lose the object that is in memory. @MTarantini's suggestion below handles save failures by rendering instead, which does not lose the memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I normally go about it is:

```
def create
  @message = Message.build(message_params)
  if @message.save
    run_at_time = @message.send_at.present? ? @message.send_at : Time.zone.now
    people = Person.in_groups(message_params[:group_ids])
    if people.any?
      people.each do |person|
        person.delay(run_at: run_at_time).send_message(@message.body)
      end
      flash[:success] = 'Messages on their way!'
      redirect_to_root_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'No people to send messages to.'
      render 'new'
    end
  else
    flash[:danger] = 'There was an error with message creation.'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

That way @message.save will return true or false, and depending on whether it succeeds through validations you can have it render the form, or redirect to root.

I also added a bit of code to show an error if there are not any people in the groups to send messages to. Not directly related to question, but I noticed the possibility.

Comment: This works but can you show me a way without the error strings you made. I just want the rails error messages to dislplay.

Comment: The way you're displaying errors in the view will still work because @message.errors will hold them. I just added the flashes to display a message at the top of the page (or wherever you're displaying them) to the user so they quickly know an error occurred, and they can scroll down to see what gave the error. If you don't want them you can just delete the flash[:danger] lines and your errors will still display in the view.